# EF Core + AWS Aurora Read/Write endpoints

Tags: entity-framework, ef-core-2.2, amazon-aurora

AWS Aurora gives me 4 endpoints:

```
myproj-cluster-1.cluster-xyz.region.rds.amazon.com (write)
myproj-cluster-1.cluster-ro-xyz.region.rds.amazon.com (read only)
myproj.xyz.region.rds.amazon.com (write)
myproj-rds.xyz.region.rds.amazon.com (read only)
```

I guess I should stick with the "cluster" version of those endpoints. Am I correct?

Also, does EF core supports multiple endpoints? In other words, is there a way to make EF Core connect to the read replica if I'm doing read only operations, and access the writer/master endpoint if I'm doing write operations?

Comment: Hi Pedro, do you mind accepting the answer if it helped? Let me know if you need more clarification on something.

Answer (score 0):

Aurora vends out 3 endpoints:

1. Cluster reader endpoint - DNS round robin between your reader instances
2. Cluster writer endpoint - Points to the writer instance always
3. One instance endpoint for each instance present in the cluster

From your list, it looks like you have 2 instances in your cluster - hence the 4th endpoint. In almost all cases, you should use the cluster endpoints for your application. The only place where customers use instance endpoints is if they want to have some customized load balancing.

As for EF - I don't have any specific pointers, but defining custom endpoints should be doable. Others might be able to help you better with that.